# "Sending of the message failed" when trying to sign a message with a gpg key (Thunderbird 102.11.2) using a gmail account

Tags: email, thunderbird, gnupg, mail, gmail

I'm trying to troubleshoot why thunderbird may be refusing to send a message when adding a signature to it, but works fine otherwise? Is it possible that gmail is blocking/refusing to process gpg signed emails? Is there any way in thunderbird to get more information on the error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the pinentry program from curses-based to a graphical one (qt) by adding a `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` file and adding to it `pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-gnome3` entry.

It would be good if Thunderbird warned you that it couldn't run `pinentry-curses` or if it could switch to a gtk/qt one automatically, because this was only a wild guess really.

Option to configure which pinetry program to use would be particularly nice, because then you could keep using 'curses' by default.